# junit test cannot catch exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

I wrote some test code.

First, I wrote the saving data unit test. It is okay.

Second, I want to test duplicated exceptions when saving data.

So I save data and save same data again.
But My test code fail.

Here is my test code.

```java
    @Test
    public void testSaveFail_DuplicateIdHash() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> workloadDto = createWorkload(); // created data
        String content = TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonString(workloadDto); // convert map to string
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/save")
                .content(content)
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn(); // pass 


        
        mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/save")
                .content(content)
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError()) // fail
                .andReturn();
        int responseStatus = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        logger.info("response:{}", responseStatus);
    }
```

My idea write
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'itititi' for key 'id_hash_UNIQUE'

and fail the test.

I don't know how to pass my duplicate exception test.

Comment: Are you sure that on `DuplicateKeyException` 5xx error is returned and not 4xx for instance?

Comment: @AleksandrErokhin Yes, I received 500 error code.